# Shapeless: is there a way to get Hlist type from a case class or a tuple

Tags: scala, tuples, shapeless

I'm totally new to shapeless. I create a case class from a list as following:

```
val list = Seq(Some(1), Some(1.0), ...)
val y =
  list
    .toHList[Option[Int]::Option[Double]::Option[Int]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::Option[Double]::HNil]

val z = y.get.tupled
val aa = YieldVariables.tupled(z)
```

It works well but I'm wondering if there is a way not to write all these types in the `toHList[Here]` part.

So I want to know if something like `list.toHList[find the type yourself]` or `list.getTypesForHlist` or yet `MyCaseClass.getTypesForHlist` that results to `Option[Int]::Option[Double]...` exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For case classes (and tuples, these are also case classes!), use `Generic`:

```
case class A(i: Int, s: String)
shapeless.Generic[A].to(A(1, "")) // Int :: String :: HNil
```

This is not possible to do on `Seq`. Indeed, as soon as you've called the constructor, the information about how many element you passed to that constructor is gone from a type perspective. Shapeless also has `SingletonProductArgs`: a macro for a varargs like syntax that returns an `HList` instead of a `Seq`.